# valuewhen() is not providing the correct value

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get the value of the most recent pivot high and pivot low points.
As far as i know valuewhen() is the easiest way to grab those values.

When i tried this and compared to the pivot high and low labels, it shows that the valuewhen() is showing completely different values.

Does someone know what i did wrong?

```
Pivotprd = input.int(defval=10, title='Pivot Point Period', minval=10, maxval=50)  //How many pivot points. Lower value results in more points.

var float ph = na
var float pl = na
ph := ta.pivothigh(Pivotprd, Pivotprd)
pl := ta.pivotlow(Pivotprd, Pivotprd)

var float phVal = na
phVal := ta.valuewhen(ph, close, 1)
var float plVal = na
plVal := ta.valuewhen(pl, close, 1)
```

I've noticed that valuewhen() grabs the value of the bar that is (Pivotprd) after ph was true. I don't understand wht it does this

Comment: Fixed the problem. Will comment awnser below

Answer (score 0):

```
var float phVal = na
phVal := ta.valuewhen(ph, close, 0)
var float plVal = na
plVal := ta.valuewhen(pl, close, 0)
```

Try replacing the occurence parameter with 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pivotprd = input.int(defval=10, title='Pivot Point Period', minval=10, maxval=50)  
var float ph = na
var float pl = na
ph := ta.pivothigh(Pivotprd, Pivotprd)
pl := ta.pivotlow(Pivotprd, Pivotprd)
var float phVal = na
phVal := ta.valuewhen(ph, high[Pivotprd], 0)
var float plVal = na
plVal := ta.valuewhen(pl, low[Pivotprd], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you say you want the value of the pivots when they occur, your code is actually looking for the `close` at that point. Assuming that is your objective, you need to go back to the pivot when it is detected, which is `Pivotprd` bars before the detection point, so here we:

- Offset the value returned by `valuewhen()` using `close[Pivotprd]`.
- Use occurrence zero in `valuewhen()` to return the most recent occurrence.

```
//@version=5
indicator("", "", true)
Pivotprd = input.int(defval=10, title='Pivot Point Period', minval=10, maxval=50)  //How many pivot points. Lower value results in more points.

ph = ta.pivothigh(Pivotprd, Pivotprd)
pl = ta.pivotlow(Pivotprd, Pivotprd)
phVal = ta.valuewhen(ph, close[Pivotprd], 0)
plVal = ta.valuewhen(pl, close[Pivotprd], 0)

plot(phVal)
plot(plVal, color = color.orange)
plotchar(ph, "ph", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(pl, "pl", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]